# Creating bot using Yeomen botbuilder

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Iam creating a bot using Yeomen botbuilder generator. I successfully installed botbuilder using

```
 npm install -g yo generator-botbuilder
```

then configured bot and when I try to run bot using `npm start` or `node index.js`
Error is coming like this.

```
C:\Users\Anant\Documents\Bots\anant>node index.js
C:\Users\Anant\Documents\Bots\anant\node_modules\restify\lib\request.js:848
    Request.prototype.closed = function closed() {
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter
    at patch (C:\Users\Anant\Documents\Bots\anant\node_modules\restify\lib\request.js:848:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anant\Documents\Bots\anant\node_modules\restify\lib\server.js:33:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anant\Documents\Bots\anant\node_modules\restify\lib\index.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I tried to update all packages.
Tried to install windows-build-tools again, But its coming that its depreciated and included in node only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to an incompatibility between restify versions prior to `v10.0.0` and Node `v18.x`. I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/4392) to update the botbuilder yo templates, but you can fix this issue by updating restify in your project to `v10.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps >>open terminal in VS code (run the commands) >> npm remove restify >> npm i  restify >> npm config set registry https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-v4-js-daily/npm/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).